# Local storage is not saving my inputs and goes away on refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I finally got my local storage to show the value of the text area but now my local storage is not saving the value of the text input. The value will show up in local storage like I said but when I refresh the page the text input does not stay. Not sure if I'm calling it wrong or my local storage itself is written wrong. The deployed page is here if it helps with seeing it. https://doolittle28.github.io/work-day-scheduler/

```js
var time9 = (parseInt($('#9').attr('data-value')));
var time10 = (parseInt($('#10').attr('data-value')));
var time11 = (parseInt($('#11').attr('data-value')));
var time12 = (parseInt($('#12').attr('data-value')));
var time13 = (parseInt($('#13').attr('data-value')));
var time14 = (parseInt($('#14').attr('data-value')));
var time15 = (parseInt($('#15').attr('data-value')));
var time16 = (parseInt($('#16').attr('data-value')));
var time17 = (parseInt($('#17').attr('data-value')));

// Keeps date on the page
var date = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");
$("#currentDay").html(date);



// Event listender for saving activities in timeslots to local storage
$('.saveBtn').on('click', function () {

    localStorage.setItem("time9", $("#input9").val());
    localStorage.setItem("time10", $("#input10").val());
    localStorage.setItem("time11", $("#input11").val());
    localStorage.setItem("time12", $("#input12").val());
    localStorage.setItem("time13", $("#input13").val());
    localStorage.setItem("time14", $("#input14").val());
    localStorage.setItem("time15", $("#input15").val());
    localStorage.setItem("time16", $("#input16").val());
    localStorage.setItem("time17", $("#input17").val());
});

// Changes color of timeslot container depending on time
function color() {
    var currentTime = moment().hour(); // variable to pull current time from

    // 9am timeslot
    if (time9 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts9').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time9 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts9').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts9').addClass('past')
    };

    // 10am timeslot
    if (time10 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts10').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time10 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts10').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts10').addClass('past')
    };

    // 11am timeslot
    if (time11 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts11').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time11 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts11').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts11').addClass('past')
    };

    // 12pm timeslot
    if (time12 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts12').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time12 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts12').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts12').addClass('past')
    };

    // 1pm timeslot
    if (time13 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts13').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time13 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts13').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts13').addClass('past')
    };

    // 2pm timeslot
    if (time14 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts14').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time14 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts14').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts14').addClass('past')
    };

    // 3pm timeslot
    if (time15 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts15').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time15 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts15').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts15').addClass('past')
    };

    // 4pm timeslot
    if (time16 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts16').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time16 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts16').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts16').addClass('past')
    };

    // 5pm timeslot
    if (time17 > currentTime) {
        $('.acts17').addClass('future')
    }
    else if (time17 === currentTime) {
        $('.acts17').addClass('present')
    }
    else {
        $('.acts17').addClass('past')
    };



};

color(); // Runs color function to color code schedule

// Pulls time and activity from local storage for each timeslot
$("#input9").val(localStorage.getItem("abc"));
$("#input10").val((localStorage.getItem('.acts10')));
$("#input11").val((localStorage.getItem('.acts11')));
$("#input12").val((localStorage.getItem('.acts12')));
$("#input13").val((localStorage.getItem('.acts13')));
$("#input14").val((localStorage.getItem('.acts14')));
$("#input15").val((localStorage.getItem('.acts15')));
$("#input16").val((localStorage.getItem('.acts16')));
$("#input17").val((localStorage.getItem('.acts17')));
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="9" data-value="9">9:00am</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts9" id="input9" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="10" data-value="10">10:00am</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts10" id="input10"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="11" data-value="11">11:00am</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts11" id="input11"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="12" data-value="12">12:00pm</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts12" id="input12"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="13" data-value="13">1:00pm</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts13" id="input13"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="14" data-value="14">2:00pm</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts14" id="input14"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="15" data-value="15">3:00pm</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts15" id="input15"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="16" data-value="16">4:00pm</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts16" id="input16"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

      <section class="col-12 mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-2 timeslots hour" id="17" data-value="17">5:00pm</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 border border-info acts17" id="input17"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="col-2 btn btn-info saveBtn">Save</button>
      </section>

    </div>
    <!-- Timeblocks go here -->
  </div>
```

Comment: You're setting `time10` but then using `.acts10` to get it. The names have to match. As an aside, you might want to look into arrays. Doing `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, `foo25` means you have to repeat a lot of code over and over which is unsustainable and prone to bugs. Imagine if you had 300 or 3000 elements in a list, a common occurrence.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you! I tried calling the value again but it wouldn't work but after reading your comment I went back and realized I needed to call time10, time11, etc in the getItem. I started this and got really deep and didn't want to go back and refactor it into an array. You're thinking like a variable that holds all the time and inputs as like objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set local Storage by name of `time10` but when you get by name of`.acts 10` ,
this name is not set on localstorage.
You should get from localstorage like down code.

```
 $("#input9").val(localStorage.getItem("time9"));
 $("#input10").val((localStorage.getItem('time10')));
 $("#input11").val((localStorage.getItem('time11')));
 $("#input12").val((localStorage.getItem('time12')));
 $("#input13").val((localStorage.getItem('time13')));
 $("#input14").val((localStorage.getItem('time14')));
 $("#input15").val((localStorage.getItem('time15')));
 $("#input16").val((localStorage.getItem('time16')));
 $("#input17").val((localStorage.getItem('time17')));
```